# Building OpenCV.js with wrappers for projectPoints + solvePnP

Tags: javascript, opencv, porting, opencv-solvepnp

Porting to JavaScript: "Cannot register public name 'projectPoints' twice"

I did the following:

1. git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
2. git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
3. I added the following in def get_build_flags(self) of opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py:
       flags += "-s USE_PTHREADS=0 "
4. I enabled the build flag in def get_cmake_cmd(self): of opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py:`-DBUILD_opencv_calib3d` set to `ON`
5. I added the following def get_cmake_cmd(self): of opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py:`-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules`
6. I appended `js` inside ocv_define_module at the end of WRAP list of opencv/modules/calib3d/CMakeLists.txt. In opencv/modules/features2d/CMakeLists.txt and opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/CMakeLists.txt also I added  "js" parameter in ocv_define_module.
7. I added `solvePnP`and 'projectPoints' in the calib3d module in the opencv/modules/js/src/embindgen.py

calib3d = {'': ['findHomography','calibrateCameraExtended', 'drawFrameAxes', 
'getDefaultNewCameraMatrix', 'initUndistortRectifyMap', 'solvePnP','projectPoints']}

8. I added the calib3d module to the makeWhiteList in the opencv/modules/js/src/embindgen.py

white_list = makeWhiteList([core, imgproc, objdetect, video, dnn, features2d, photo, aruco, calib3d])

9. I added "using namespace aruco;" in the opencv/modules/js/src/core_bindings.cpp
10. I built OpenCV.js using the following command: 
    sudo python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=${EMSCRIPTEN} --clean_build_dir --build_test

Before adding these wrappers, it compiled perfectly without errors. Now in my tests.html I have the following message:

```
Downloading...
tests.html:61 Running...
tests.html:61 Exception thrown, see JavaScript console
opencv.js:24 Uncaught 
BindingError
message: "Cannot register public name 'projectPoints' twice"
name: "BindingError"
stack: "BindingError: Cannot register public name 'projectPoints' twice↵    at BindingError.<anonymous>
```

So seems like the overload functions are preventing me from porting them to JavaScript.

Any suggestions please of how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: i am facing the similar issue and for the surprise there are no solutions which i came across